# Testing if object is not deleted

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, design-patterns

My object creates an thread and that thread modifies object-creator during his life cycle. The problem is, that thread should not invoke objects methods when it is destroyed. I have found some sollution for that problem and I would like to know if it is best one.

```
class A
{
    shared_ptr<int> guard = make_shared<int>(0);
public:
    weak_ptr<int> getGuard() { return guard; }
    void method() {}
    A()
    {
        thread([this]
        {
            const auto &guard = getGuard();
            while(!guard.expired()) 
                method();
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Are you intending to detach the thread that gets created so that the thread does not block `A`'s constructor?

Comment: Yes, in real-life code, thread construction does not block main thread. To be honest, new thread is not even created in costructor. I just tried to simplify example a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ensure that the object is not destroyed while you're calling the `method`, but can be destroyed at other times, you'll need to keep a `weak_ptr` on the object itself, and lock that while you call the method.  Something like:

```
class A : std::enable_shared_from_this<A>
{
public:
    void method() {}
    A()
    {
        std::weak_ptr<A> self(shared_from_this());
        thread([=self]
        {
            while (auto This = self.lock())
                This->method();
        }).detach();
    }
};
```

This object can now only be created via `make_shared` -- trying to do it any other way results in undefined behavior and will probably crash.

Answer (score 3):

The while loop you have is not a thread-safe way of ensuring `method` only gets called while the object pointed to by `guard` still exists.  The reason for this is that another thread may cause the destruction of the object in between the call to `expired` and the call to `method`.

The safe way to perform this check is to attempt to promote the weak pointer to a shared pointer:

```
while (true)
{
    shared_ptr<int> sp = getGuard().lock();
    if (sp)
    {
        method();
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

By promoting the weak pointer to a shared pointer, the calling code participates in ownership of the object for the duration of the call to `method`, ensuring that it cannot be destroyed while the calling code is using it.

You've also failed to join or detach the thread.  From your example it looks like you want to detach it so that `A`'s constructor can exit before the thread finishes executing.  In this case, your code should look like this:

```
thread([this]
{
    ...
}).detach();
```

Comment: The first part of your answer is very important for me. I overlooked that thread unsafety. Pointer promotion will not help (it points to a member of a class, not an object), but wrapping that lines with some mutex will do the job.
It is some pseudocode to illustrate overall idea, anyway thanks for suggestion about detach().
Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't really help -- the lock will only prevent the destruction of the shared `int` and not the object.  So you might still acquire the lock, then another thread destroys the object, then you call method on the destroyed object.  You need to keep a `weak_ptr` to the object itself, and lock that.

Comment: @Chris Dodd You're right, I didn't properly think through all the details, I was more concerned with the while loop check.  Feel free to edit that into this answer or leave a new one, otherwise I'll have to come back to this later to make sure that detail gets added.